# Issue with UI access from Background worker

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I'm shifting a project over from winforms to WPF. When my code was based on WinForms I used (this.InvokeRequired) to check if the thread has access. Now I use the following code based on my Mainform :

```
    // this is the delegate declaration to Allow Background worker thread to write to Log Output
    delegate void LogUpdateCallBack(String LogMessage);

    // method to update the Log Window from the Background Thread
    public void LogUpdate(String LogMessage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entering");
        if (!Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread doesn't have UI access");
            LogUpdateCallBack callback = new LogUpdateCallBack(LogUpdate);
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(callback, LogMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread has UI access");
            listBox_Output.Items.Add(LogMessage);
            Console.WriteLine(LogMessage);
            // listBox_Output.TopIndex = listBox_Output.Items.Count - 1;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
    }
```

The issue I have is that the Listbox isn't updating. There are no errors or exceptions, I've tried updating other UI controls. The LogMessage is writing into the Output window so I'm stumped.

Here's sample Console output :

```
Entering
Thread doesn't have UI access
Entering
Thread has UI access
My LogMessage is output here 
Exiting
Exiting
Entering
Thread doesn't have UI access
Entering
Thread has UI access
My LogMessage is output here 
Exiting
Exiting
```

I've tried updating other UI controls just to check if it's an issue with my Listbox but with no luck.

Other than switching over to CheckAccess() the only other major change I've made in the new WPF code is to base all the code running in the Background worker in another Class .. I'm not sure if this could be part of the issue ?.

--

[@JonRaynor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431828/issue-with-ui-access-from-background-worker/6431941#6431941)

I tried your idea :

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new LogUpdateCallBack(LogUpdate), LogMessage)
```

However my Listbox still isn't updating, if I output

```
Console.WriteLine(listBox_Output);
```

I see the list box array growing :

```
System.Windows.Controls.ListBox Items.Count:2020
System.Windows.Controls.ListBox Items.Count:2021
System.Windows.Controls.ListBox Items.Count:2022
System.Windows.Controls.ListBox Items.Count:2023
System.Windows.Controls.ListBox Items.Count:2024
System.Windows.Controls.ListBox Items.Count:2025
```

But no change in the form. This is very confusing !.

Comment: Any databinding on the Listbox? Does an Items.Add("test") from the Page_Load event work?

Comment: No DataBinding .. I'm updating the ListBox from other areas of my code with no difficulty. I've also tried updating other UI controls in case it was down to Listbox issues .. with no luck.

Comment: One further strange thing to note .. is that if I output listBox_Output in the Console I can see the items are being added (it reports the item count), so it seems that my items are being added, however the UI is not being updated at all. I've tried  listBox_Output.InvalidateVisual(); with no effect.

Comment: One thing I see as different is I am using this.Dispatcher where 'this' is the form/container that contains the list box and you are using Application.Current.   I am not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Very weird, I took you code as is and created a new WPF application. I dropped a list box on the Grid as well as a button. Then I simply spawned a new thread from the button click event and called LogUpdate from that thead.  It worked.  Something else is going on, I am not sure what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this.

My issue was that as I was calling the LogUpdate method from both another thread AND another class, therefore I needed to pass a reference to my main form which contained the listbox into this class rather than create a new instance of the main form in the secondary class.

so rather than have this declaration in my secondary class :

```
public MainWindow MainForm = new MainWindow();
```

I needed to pass a reference of the form into the method in the secondary class :

```
    public void Plot(BackgroundWorker worker, MainWindow MainForm)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just started on WPF as well and had to relearn from the old WinForms way.  I've been using BeginInvoke() and this type of syntax on my screens (forms)...

```
public delegate void WorkCompleted();

        /// <summary>
        /// Marks the end of the progress
        /// </summary>
        private void ProgressComplete()
        {
            if (!this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new WorkCompleted(ProgressComplete), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, null);
            }
            else
            {
                this.buttonClose.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                this.progressBarStatus.IsIndeterminate = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion .. I'll try this method out and see if I get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, all the UI controls are derived from DispatcherObject. That means your ListBox control is, itself, a dispatch-capable object. Try invoking the Dispatcher on that object instead of relying on the form itself. Take out the parameter on your delegate (because you have access to the LogMessage variable anyway) and it'd look something like:

```
public void LogUpdate(string LogMessage)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entering");
    if (listBox_Output.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        listBox_Output.Dispatcher.Invoke(new LogUpdateCallBack(delegate
        {
            listBox_Output.Items.Add(LogMessage);
        }));
        Console.WriteLine(LogMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however the issue was in my misunderstanding of the declaring an instance of the MainForm in another class, I assumed this would give me access to the mainform however it merely created a new instance of it .. so when I updated controls I didn't see a result.